# Microsoft Translator Speech ,No return,I used C++ websocketpp

Tags: c++, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I try  to use **Microsoft Translator** Speech API . I am using c++ `websocketpp`, I confirm that I have sent the audio data to server,but wait two minutes, the connection closed, because no audio is received from the client for an extended period of time.

```
void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    m_open = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::ifstream f("./HelloWorld.wav");
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(f)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())
    m_endpoint.send(hdl,str,websocketpp::frame::opcode::BINARY);
}
```

Why?

Who can help me?

Thank you and regards.

**Send data:**

[image]

**Wait two minutes:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

emmmm,I solved the question,we need to add some silences at the end to tell the service that it is the end of the sentences.We make sure they are 0x00 byte,I made a mistake ,the data sent comes with additional information---pointer? Modify this error,I got a correct return.